# Java AWS Lambda function takes long time to upload using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS Lambda and I am using following things to create a service.

> Compute : Lambda
>   Database : DynamoDB
>   Storage & Content Delivery : S3 Bucket
>   Programming Language : Java
>   Editor : Eclipse

Wherever I do any changes in any class file I need to re-upload the lambda function from eclipse (**Amazon Web Services -> Upload Function to AWS Lambda**).
It's taking long time to upload.

As per my understanding it's uploading whole project instead of only the changed classes to S3 bucket that's why it's taking lots of time. So I am facing problem while debugging the code.

Is there any way by which I can upload only the changed classes so that it will take less time to upload? Or is there any other way by which I can debug such services locally without uploading anything in S3 bucket?

Comment: Lambda are function and should be very small. How big is the ZIP you try to upload?

Comment: I am not uploading any zip file from aws console. I as using eclipse to do so.

Comment: The total size of a lambda function showing in the aws console is 45 MB.

Comment: sure but how big is the lambda function with all the JARs. What dependencies do you have?

Comment: So it always uploads 45 MB!! That's not the idea of Lambda. What's in the 45 MB!

Comment: I have around 6 to 7 classes in it. Also AWS SDK is there in that project. I don't know if I am uploading it wrongly.